# How to send files through moodle api REST

Tags: php, rest, api, moodle

I'm working on a mobile app and I need to send files together with the post.
I looked at the documentation and have the core_files_upload function but there is no clear information on how to do it and I would like to know how to upload files via REST api from Moodle.

Comment: I tested so much that it does not fit here, what I wanted was an explanation of how it works core_files_upload methods or another way to send file to moodle via REST.

Comment: Uploading files, and storing them, is a little complex in Moodle. Could you describe what you would like to upload files for? Where would they be used? What users will access them? Do you know about the File API? Contexts? File areas, etc...?

Comment: Hello thank you for the answer
I'm going to clarify a bit, I'm looking forward to posting a file to a post within the forum, as it can be done in normal moodle, except that this will be done in a mobile app.
Describing:
The user through the mobile app will send a post containing text and a file that can be any type.
On the api files, I did not see in the documentation what seginifies its parameters like context, File areas, etc ... could you clarify to me?

thank you!